# Google VM connecting Global ELB

Tags: google-cloud-platform

One of my app needs to connect to two services (based on the URL path having same base path) in some other VPC (and in few cases in other region as well). Both apps are on Google VPC.

My requirement is to add hostname header at the intermediate layer.
I tried using Internal load balancer but it does not provide option to add the header. So, I am evaluating option of using Google ELB (where this option is available).

My question is if I use ELB, how will traffic route?

Will it route via internet?

Or will it be via VPC or will ELB play smartly and create direct routes?

Comment: I recommend using a VPC connector. Otherwise, edit your post to provide more details. Items such as `what is the service` are important. The service must be a supported backend. Why is `google-app-engine` tagged? Why doe the route matter?

Comment: removed the app engine....added accidently.

Comment: It is not clear what your problem is. You are using descriptions that are not defined such as `add hostname header at the intermediate layer`. You mention routing yet failed to answer my question. Please clearly define your problem before posting.